# Underline not working for double line headings

Tags: html, css

I have a football blog, and sometimes my titles are quite big, so I have to insert a line break to make it fit in the space I want. However, when that happens, the underline animation when you hover over the heading does not work for both lines anymore.

```css
#latestarticles li{
  list-style-type: none;
}


.testarticleimg{
  position:relative;
  right:-23%;
  width:45%;
  max-width:45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}


.Articletitle > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #98c5e9;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.Articletitle > a:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.testarticleimg:hover{
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.1); 
}

.articleinfo{
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;
  font-size:15px;
  opacity:0.4;
  position:relative;
  right:-23%;
  top:2%;
  width:47.5%;
}

.articleinfo p{
  width:47.5%;
}

.articleinfo a{
  color:black;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.articleinfo a:hover{
  color:#98c5e9;
}

.articleshr{
  width:63%;
  opacity:0.1;
  position:relative;
  left:-5%;
  bottom:5%;
}

.Articletitle{
  position:relative;
  right:-23%;
  top:-2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;
}

.Articletitle a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#98c5e9;
}
```

```html
<li><article>
          <span class="Articletitle"><a href="article02052021.html">Klopp makes controversial comments about <br>Man City and COVID</a></span>
          <span class="articleinfo"><br><br><br><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> February 5th 2021
  <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> By Shuyan Duan <br><br><p>In a recent press conference by Liverpool manager Jurgen Klopp, the former Borrussia Dortmund coach made comments on the upcoming clash against Manchester City, one which many believe will define the title race for the rest of the season. He also opined on the reason why City have an advantage right now, which will sureley cause much controversy.<br><br><a href="article02052021.html">Read More ></a></p></span>
          <br>
          <br><br><div class="imgBox"><img src="https://www.thisisanfield.com/wp-content/uploads/P2021-02-03-Liverpool_Brighton-23.jpg" class="testarticleimg"/></div>
          <br><br><br><br>
  <hr class="articleshr" id="testarticlehr">
  
  
        </article></li>
```

Does someone have a solution to make the underline appear on both the lines of the heading? (p.s: the heading is the text in blue)

Comment: you are using before pseudoelement for the line. As it is only one lement, you can not use it for every line. If you have a maximum of 2 lines, you could use before and after. But i would suggest to find another solution for this